# Classic ASP - Issues with data data access through SQL

Tags: mysql, asp-classic

I have been working with classic ASP and database access through it. The database im using is MySQL. The ASP pages are running on IIS 7.
I developed two ASP pages. First, here is the schema im working with-

Book = (**b_id**, title, pages, price, p_id)

Publisher = (**p_id**, name, country)

p_id in Book is a foreign key from Publisher.

Now, in one script, when adding record in Publisher, i first check whether similar record exists and if it does then report that to user. That script works fine.

But in other script to insert record in Book, i first check whether the specified publisher exists or not. But for some reason, that doesnt work at all. That is, when i query the Publisher table to get all records for comparision, the RecordCount property of the RecordSet object returns -1.

I have checked both scripts extensively for errors and there are none.

Why is the same code for the same purpose not working in one but working in the other ?

The working code -

```
flag = false
temprs.Open "select country from publisher where name='" & pubname & "'", conn
if temprs.RecordCount <> 0 then
    do while not temprs.EOF
        if temprs.fields("country") = pubcountry then
            flag = true
            exit do
        end if
        temprs.MoveNext
    loop
end if
```

It goes into the loop in the above code.

And the code thats not working -

```
q = "select p_id from publisher where name='" & bookpub & "'"
prs.Open q, conn
pins = false
if prs.RecordCount > 0 then
    pid = prs.fields("p_id")
    pins = true
end if
```

Here, prs.RecordCount returns -1. All variables have been Dim-med in the earlier portion of the code.

Comment: Are you certain that the code is the same?  If it is, output your sql statements to the screen and check them.

Comment: Code is same. I did output the queries on screen and they are fine.

Comment: is there a difference in the way you are calling them? rs.open / con.execute ..

Comment: Are you losing the value to p_id in the section that's not working.  Also, can you post the relevant code?

Comment: @SearchAndResQ : Nope..its the same..

Comment: @CMKanode : I declare a variable and store pid in that. However, the problem is that i dont get a chance to retrieve the pid at all because as the RecordCount returns -1, i cant fetch any value..I've added the code in my post.

Comment: Your code is different.  "if temprs.RecordCount <> 0 then" is not the same as "if prs.RecordCount > 0 then".  It is possible that temprs has a recordcount of -1, too, except that it will evaluate as true.  With later versions of IIS, I have had issues with RecordCount NOT being reliable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can I offer a different solution that gives you the same result but without using recordcount:

```
q = "select p_id from publisher where name='" & bookpub & "'"
prs.Open q, conn
pins = false
if not prs.eof then
    pid = prs("p_id")
    pins = true
end if
```

Comment: It depends on the recordset setup, ADO and database you are using. A recordcount of -1 means it could not be determined. With all those variables it's a combo that is different on nearly every install and project so using the method above is a guarantee to work on any combo with the same code.